# Directive doesn't work anymore after minifying

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs

I've got a directive like this:

```
var tonicswitch = angular.module('tonicswitch', []).directive('multiSelectTonics', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            items: '=',
            default: '=',
            leftTitle: '@',
            rightTitle: '@'
        },
        templateUrl: "views/tonicswitch.html",
        link: function(scope)   {
            scope.switchItem = function(item)   {
                var index = scope.default.indexOf(item);
                if(index == -1) {
                    console.log("Add tonic");
                    scope.default.push(item);
                } else {
                    console.log("Remove tonic");
                    scope.default.splice(index, 1);
                }
            }
        }
    };
})

tonicswitch.directive('switchtonic', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            value: '='
        },
        template: '<div>{{value}}</div>'
    };
});
```

and the HTML is as follows:

```
<style>
    .switchBox .entBox {
        overflow:auto;
        height:500px; 
        width:350px;
        border:1px solid black;
        float:left;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -khtml-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        -o-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    .switchBox .entBox div:hover {
        background-color: #00FF03;
    }
    .switchBox .eBox2.entBox div:hover {
        background-color: #FF0007;
    }

    switchtonic {
        display: block;
        margin-top: 5px;
    }

    switchtonic:first-child {
        margin-top: 0;
    }
</style>

<label>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>{{leftTitle}}</th>
            <th>{{rightTitle}}</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="switchBox">
            <td>
                <div class="entBox eBox1">
                    <switchtonic ng-repeat="(key, value) in items" ng-if="default.indexOf(key) == -1" value="value.getName()" ng-click="switchItem(key)"></switchtonic>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="entBox eBox2">
                    <switchtonic ng-repeat="(key, value) in items" ng-if="default.indexOf(key) > -1" value="value.getName()" ng-click="switchItem(key)"></switchtonic>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</label>
```

In my app.js I've added the directives to my module like this:

```
angular
  .module('Gins', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngAria',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngMessages',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch',
    'parse-angular',
    'parse-angular.enhance',
    'ngDialog',
    'typeswitch',
    'tonicswitch'
  ])
```

I use the directive in my html as follows:

```
<multi-select default="selectedTypesNL" items="listOfAllNLTypes" left-title="All Types" right-title="Picked Types"></multi-select>
```

This are the vars in my controller

```
$scope.selectedTypesNL = [];
$scope.listOfAllNLTypes = {};
```

When I receive my items I do this:

```
for(var indexAllTypes = 0; indexAllTypes < $scope.types.length; indexAllTypes++){
    $scope.listOfAllNLTypes[$scope.types[indexAllTypes].getType()] = $scope.types[indexAllTypes];
}
```

Everything works fine when I just run grunt serve. When I run grunt build the directive is showing the table but doesn't repeat anything. The table stays empty. There is something that goes wrong during the minify process. I don't see any errors but when I disable minifying everything still works. Anyone an idea why this isn't working after minifying?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console? This is most likely due to the fact you're not annotating your Angular controllers etc. and hence during minification the parameter names will be replaced causing your application to stop working.

Comment: I'm always running ngAnnotate so thats why I don't need to annotate my methods I guess? No not getting any errors. Everything on the page works. There are many things that are filled up from my controllers just that directive isn't doing any repeats.

Comment: Can you verify ngAnnotate's config is correct? Could you open DevTools and debug the directive? i.e. is the controller being created but the data's not there etc.

Comment: Yes the directive created. The only thing I notice is that in the build version when I do a log in the directive that my items are empty. So the directive is runned before my items are retrieved from parse. But when I receive my items I fill up my object that is coupled to the directive in the html tag. I've edited my question with the html and the fillup code.

Comment: Could it be the fact that you're using `default` as an object property? `default` is now a reserved keyword in ES6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by arjabbar it was the default keyword. I renamed it and now everything works fine even with htmlmin enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Very weird but when I disable htmlmin in the build task in my grunt file everything works.